# How to establish $\sum_{d|n}d\phi(d)$

Tags: number-theory, functions

[image][image]

I am focusing on #5(b). I do not understand how they go from what I have to the answer. Those are r's at the end.

Comment: I don't understand how I am supposed to use that. I used the following facts: $$\sum_{d|n}d=\frac{p_1^{k_1+1}}{p_1-1}\ldots = \sigma(n)$$ and $$\sum_{d|n}\phi(d)=n$$

Comment: We would have $$\frac{p^2-1}{p-1}p = p^2+1$$

Comment: Why did you delete your comments?

Comment: Just for curiosity, which book are you referencing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $\sum_{d\mid n} d\varphi(d)$ is multiplicative, so we only need to calculate $\sum_{d\mid n} d\varphi(d)$ for $n$ of the form $p^k$.

In that case, the sum is
$$1+\sum_{i=1}^k p^i p^{i-1}(p-1)=1+\sum_{i=1}^k p(p-1)(p^2)^{i-1}.$$
The sum is almost a geometric series, apart from the first term. Note that the geometric series part has common ratio $p^2$. The sum of the geometric series part is
$$p(p-1)\frac{p^{2k}-1}{p^2-1}.$$
This simplifies to $\dfrac{p^{2k+1}-p}{p+1}$. Finally, add $1$ and simplify.

Comment: Where did you get the summation in the first line from? I don't seem to see that in my book. Is there any way to establish this with the comment up top and the second picture?

Comment: Look at a "typical" divisor $d$ of $p^k$. It is given by $d=p^i$. And $\varphi(p^{i})=p^{i-1}(p-1)$, except this doesn't work for the divisor $d=1$. So, apart from the $d\varphi(d)$ for $d=1$, we have $d\varphi(d)=[p^i][p^{i-1}(p-1)]$. Now sum from $i=1$ to $i=k$, and add in the almost forgotten first term $[1][1]$.

Comment: One cannot get it from the expression you got for $\sum_{d\mid n} d\varphi(d)$. For you sort of assumed that this sum is $n \sum_{d\mid n} \varphi(d)$, and you wrote down an expression for $\sum_{d\mid n}\varphi(d)$, and multiplied by $n$.

Comment: I know this is pretty simple but I don't see how you got your second summation in the first line. I can see how you would have $$1+\sum_{i=1}^kp^ip^{i-1}(p-1)$$

Comment: I took out a common factor of $p(p-1)$. So (to change things a bit from the answer) we want $p(p-1)\sum_1^k p^{2i-2}$. This is $p(p-1)\sum_1^n (p^2)^{i-1}$. Now I assume you can sum the geometric series.

Comment: Ahhhh, I have finally got it! Thank you so much. I don't understand why this seemed so complicated to me. It shouldn't have been so difficult.

Comment: You are welcome. My guess is that you made it complicated by trying to go to "formulas" too quickly, instead of working out what the sum would be for say $n=p^3$.

Comment: Yeah our professor always tells us to try a few cases first to see if we can find the pattern or the method to do it for the general case and I guess I did not take his advice.

Comment: Certainly I do not expect to solve a problem without possibly very extensive playing around, unless I have solved essentially the same sort of problem already.

Comment: I wish in college we had the time, as mathematicians, to play around with things we want to figure out, rather than be rushed to get assignments done, and prepare for exams. I would like to solve problems on my own, without help, but due to this whole rush to be tested on what we have learned, it is not as simple as that.

Comment: You are right. That is why the years to $18$ are so precious. If one is academically talented, there is endless spare time for exploration.