# Evaluate $\lim_{k\to \infty}\sum_{n=1 }^k \sum_{d|n} \frac{d\phi(d)}{n^4}$

Tags: limits, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

This is a homework question and I have to evaluate

$$\lim_{k\to \infty}\sum_{n=1 }^k \sum_{d|n}  \frac{d\phi(d)}{n^4}$$

for $d|n,\ n=1$ to $k$

where $\phi$ is the Euler Phi function, and $d$ is factor of $n$

please help

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! And the sum is indexed by what? And what is Φ?

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange! It is very hard to read the question, please type it using MathJax. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I was trying to fix your statement, but as it stands it does not make sense. You take the limit over $k$, but the $k$ does not appear in the sum. You then say *for $d | n, n = 1$ to $k$*, which is hard to make sense of. Do you mean to take a double sum, where the first sum goes over $n$, and the second over the divisors of $n$? So $\lim_{k \to \infty}\sum_{n = 1}^k \sum_{d | n} \cdots$?

Comment: yes I was meant to say limk→∞∑kn=1∑d|n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the function $a(n)=\sum_{d\mid n} d\varphi(d)$ is multiplicative and from [How to establish $\sum_{d|n}d\phi(d)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/752732/how-to-establish-sum-dnd-phid) we have that
$$a(p^k)=\frac{p^{2k+1}+1}{p+1}.$$
Therefore
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a(n)}{n^4}=\prod_{p\in \mathbb{P}}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{a(p^k)}{p^{4k}}=\prod_{p\in \mathbb{P}}\frac{1}{p+1}\left(\frac{p}{1-1/p^2}+\frac{1}{1-1/p^4}
\right)
=\prod_{p\in \mathbb{P}}\frac{(1-1/p^3)}{(1-1/p^2)(1-1/p^4)}$$
where $\mathbb{P}$ is the set of primes.
Can you take it from here?

Comment: I've got it! thanks a lot

Comment: @우준혁 Please show your efforts. Edit your post and show under your question how we can go on from here.