# Summing a series with number-theoretic coefficients

Tags: number-theory, summation, mobius-function

Is there a simpler form to $f(x)=\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{d|r}d\mu(d)\right)x^r/r$  where $\mu(d)$ is the Mobius function and $\sum_{d|r}$ is a sum over the divisors $d$ of $r$?

I searched the literature and didn't find that this sum has been calculated before. I also tried solving it using the Lambert series (I found that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(x^n)=-\log(1-x)$). I also tried plotting the function, which converges in the range $[0,1)$, but was unable to fit it to any relatively simple function. I am not sure I know what else I can try (I am not a mathematician).

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: I searched the literature and didn't find that this sum has been calculated before. 
I also tried solving it using the Lambert series (I found that $\sum_{n=1}}^{\infty} f(x^n)=-\log(1-x)$). 
I also tried plotting the function, which converges in the range [0,1), but was unable to fit it to any relatively simple function. 
I am not sure I know what else I can try (I am not a mathematician).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/752732/how-to-establish-sum-dnd-phid may help.

Comment: Well one thing one can do is reversie the order of summation, giving \begin{align*}f(x) &= \sum_{d = 1}^\infty d \mu(d) \sum_{r : d \mid r} \frac{x^r}{r} \\& = \sum_{d = 1}^\infty d \mu(d) \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{x^{kd}}{kd} \\& = - \sum_{d = 1}^\infty \mu(d)\log(1 - x^d).\end{align*}  Probably there are other ways to play around -- e.g., the derivative $f'$ is (essentially) the Lambert series of $d \mu(d)$ -- but I'm not sure how much nicer one can hope to get.